# Auto Increment file name in Sharepoint Form infopath

Tags: infopath, submit

[image]I used this as my reference:

[Auto-numbering InfoPath forms when they are submitted to a SharePoint form library](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/autonumber-infopath-form-submitted-sharepoint-library.htm)

I followed that link  but it wont work correctly,instead of having 1,2,3... as filename
it creates NaN as it's file name.. what should I do?

look at the image:

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of the field `RFQ No`? What is the data validation? What rules are applied? How is the field populated? Put the details in the question.

Answer (score 1):

NaN is the error code for "not a number". The steps you take to increment do not result in a number. If you are using the MAX() function as described in the tutorial, check that the field you are using in that function is a number, not text.

Note the "caveat" on the tutorial: If the library does not yet contain any documents, the Max() function will return NaN. You must name the first form manually.

Comment: ahhh okay ill try

Comment: telyn, i did what you said but i still get NaN... what should i do?

Comment: How many items are in the library?

Comment: items? You mean textboxes?? i got 14 textboxes and a repeating section

Comment: No, the library where you want to save the form. How many forms are already in the library?

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: i have 1 form..

Comment: Yeah i created my first form manually and named it 1.